# How to say "I recently learned how to speak japanese" in japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation, words, conjugations, syntax

How to say "I recently learned how to speak Japanese" in Japanese?
is it:

> watashi wa hanasemashita nihongo koto ga saikin manabimasu

or

> watashi wa nihongo hanasemashita koto ga saikin manabimasu

or Something else?

I can't read kanji so please, if you answer please don't use kanji.

Edit:Also, can someone tell me why saikin is before nihongo and not before            naraimashita in the first answer to my question?

Comment: <(I can't read kanji> I understand your situation, but I highly recommend you study kanji. Reading hiragana-only sentences is indeed a nightmare even for native speakers.

Comment: i would have probably used ばかり

Comment: 偽善じゃない？　　If you can't say that, have you really learned how to speak Japanese?

Answer (score 1):

Passing judgement about your own Japanese skills while talking with a Japanese native speaker is a little strange.  I'd recommend:

"日本語{にほんご}ができるようになっている気{き}がしています。"

(1) "気{き}がしています" adds the meaning that your opinion about your Japanese skills is yours alone.

(2) The present continuous tense "~~になっている" adds the meaning that you think that you are on the path to becoming good, but are not quite there yet.

(3) If you want to stress your conversational skills, as opposed to your holistic skill, this might be preferred:
"日常会話{にちじょうかいわ}ができるようになっている気{き}がしています。"

Answer (score 1):

"I recently learned how to speak Japanese."

I would translate this differently depending on what the message you wish to convey.

"Watashi ha saikin, nihongo wo manandeimashita." <- Lately, I have been studying Japanese.

"Nihongo wo hanaseru you ni natta no ha saikin deshita." <- It was only recently that I become capable of speaking in Japanese.

By 'how to speak in Japanese', do you mean the speech mannerisms, phonetics, or general ability to speak the language?

Answer (score 0):

I would say 私{わたし}は最{さい}近{きん}、日{に}本{ほん}語{ご}会{かい}話{わ}を習{なら}いました, or 私{わたし}は最{さい}近{きん}、日{に}本{ほん}語{ご}の話{はな}し方{かた}を習{なら}いました.

Remark:

私 = I

最近 = recently

日本語 = Japanese

会話 = conversation

習う = to learn

話し方 = how to speak